# Properly using PERCENTILE_CONT - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

I am trying to calculate the following:

- The average of the dataset
- The median of the dataset
- The top 20% of the dataset
- The bottom 20% of the dataset

My dataset looks like this:

```
| Part | Step | Step_Start | Part_Finish |   TheTime   |
|:----:|:----:|:----------:|:-----------:|:-----------:|
|   1  |  200 |  15-Aug-18 |  19-Jun-19  | 307.4926273 |
|   2  |  200 |  7-Jun-19  |  19-Jun-19  |  11.4434375 |
|   3  |  200 |  17-Sep-18 |   4-Feb-19  | 139.4360417 |
|   4  |  200 |  30-Jan-19 |   4-Feb-19  | 4.356666667 |
|   5  |  200 |  1-Oct-18  |  18-Feb-19  | 139.4528009 |
|   6  |  200 |  13-Feb-19 |  18-Feb-19  |   4.50375   |
|   7  |  200 |  17-Oct-18 |  28-Mar-19  | 161.7007176 |
|   8  |  200 |  12-Nov-18 |  28-Mar-19  |  135.630625 |
|   9  |  200 |  25-Oct-18 |  26-Feb-19  | 123.6026968 |
|  10  |  200 |  22-Feb-19 |  26-Feb-19  | 3.628090278 |
|  11  |  200 |  30-Oct-18 |   3-Jan-19  | 64.51466435 |
|  12  |  200 |  12-Dec-18 |   3-Jan-19  | 21.48703704 |
|  13  |  200 |  15-Nov-18 |  14-Jan-19  | 59.41373843 |
|  14  |  200 |  7-Jan-19  |  14-Jan-19  | 6.621828704 |
|  15  |  200 |  15-Nov-18 |  12-Jan-19  | 57.62283565 |
|  16  |  200 |  8-Jan-19  |  12-Jan-19  | 3.264398148 |
|  17  |  200 |  15-Nov-18 |   7-Mar-19  | 111.5082523 |
|  18  |  200 |  4-Mar-19  |   7-Mar-19  | 2.153587963 |
|  19  |  200 |  16-Nov-18 |  23-May-19  | 187.6931481 |
|  20  |  200 |  16-Nov-18 |   3-Jan-19  | 47.47916667 |
|  21  |  200 |  17-Dec-18 |   3-Jan-19  | 16.62722222 |
|  22  |  200 |  20-Nov-18 |  14-Feb-19  |  85.6115625 |
|  23  |  200 |  9-Feb-19  |  14-Feb-19  | 4.520787037 |
|  24  |  200 |  19-Nov-18 |  14-Jan-19  | 55.53342593 |
|  25  |  200 |  9-Jan-19  |  14-Jan-19  | 4.721400463 |
|  26  |  200 |  26-Nov-18 |   9-Jan-19  | 43.50748843 |
|  27  |  200 |  4-Jan-19  |   9-Jan-19  | 4.417164352 |
|  28  |  200 |  26-Nov-18 |  21-Jan-19  | 55.59988426 |
|  29  |  200 |  13-Jan-19 |  21-Jan-19  |    7.535    |
|  30  |  200 |  16-Jan-19 |  21-Jan-19  | 4.618796296 |
|  31  |  200 |  26-Nov-18 |  11-Jan-19  | 45.42148148 |
|  32  |  200 |  4-Jan-19  |  11-Jan-19  | 6.316921296 |
|  33  |  200 |  4-Dec-18  |  24-Jan-19  |  50.3669213 |
|  34  |  200 |  18-Jan-19 |  24-Jan-19  | 5.589467593 |
|  35  |  200 |  4-Dec-18  |  31-Jan-19  | 57.26877315 |
|  36  |  200 |  22-Jan-19 |  31-Jan-19  | 8.240034722 |
|  37  |  200 |  5-Dec-18  |  28-Jun-19  | 204.5283912 |
|  38  |  200 |  26-Jun-19 |  28-Jun-19  | 1.508252315 |
|  39  |  200 |  9-Feb-19  |  19-Feb-19  | 9.532893519 |
|  40  |  200 |  7-Dec-18  |  14-Feb-19  | 68.51900463 |
|  41  |  200 |  5-Feb-19  |  14-Feb-19  | 8.641076389 |
|  42  |  200 |  11-Dec-18 |  25-Jan-19  | 44.50501157 |
|  43  |  200 |  22-Jan-19 |  25-Jan-19  | 2.511435185 |
|  44  |  200 |  13-Dec-18 |  17-Jan-19  | 34.43806713 |
|  45  |  200 |  14-Jan-19 |  17-Jan-19  | 2.210972222 |
|  46  |  200 |  13-Dec-18 |  24-Jan-19  | 41.38921296 |
|  47  |  200 |  17-Jan-19 |  24-Jan-19  | 6.444664352 |
|  48  |  200 |  10-Jan-19 |   7-Feb-19  | 27.43130787 |
|  49  |  200 |  1-Feb-19  |   7-Feb-19  | 5.349189815 |
|  50  |  200 |  18-Dec-18 |   4-Feb-19  | 47.50416667 |
|  51  |  200 |  29-Jan-19 |   4-Feb-19  | 5.481979167 |
|  52  |  200 |  3-Jan-19  |  30-Jan-19  | 26.46112269 |
|  53  |  200 |  23-Jan-19 |  30-Jan-19  | 6.712175926 |
|  54  |  200 |  4-Jan-19  |   5-Feb-19  | 31.49590278 |
|  55  |  200 |  30-Jan-19 |   5-Feb-19  | 5.385798611 |
|  56  |  200 |  23-Jan-19 |  20-Mar-19  |  55.296875  |
|  57  |  200 |  21-Feb-19 |  20-Mar-19  | 26.06854167 |
|  58  |  200 |  22-Jan-19 |  14-Mar-19  | 50.57989583 |
|  59  |  200 |  8-Mar-19  |  14-Mar-19  | 5.147303241 |
|  60  |  200 |  22-Jan-19 |  21-Feb-19  | 29.46405093 |
|  61  |  200 |  14-Feb-19 |  21-Feb-19  | 6.701724537 |
|  62  |  200 |  24-Jan-19 |  23-Apr-19  | 88.50689815 |
|  63  |  200 |  17-Apr-19 |  23-Apr-19  | 5.725405093 |
|  64  |  200 |  28-Jan-19 |  21-Feb-19  | 23.50082176 |
|  65  |  200 |  13-Feb-19 |  21-Feb-19  | 7.115717593 |
|  66  |  200 |  31-Jan-19 |  28-Feb-19  | 27.55881944 |
|  67  |  200 |  25-Feb-19 |  28-Feb-19  | 2.633738426 |
|  68  |  200 |  31-Jan-19 |  27-Feb-19  | 26.46105324 |
|  69  |  200 |  23-Feb-19 |  27-Feb-19  | 3.531423611 |
|  70  |  200 |  1-Feb-19  |  28-Feb-19  | 26.45835648 |
|  71  |  200 |  27-Feb-19 |  28-Feb-19  | 0.471296296 |
|  72  |  200 |  6-Feb-19  |  27-Feb-19  | 20.54436343 |
|  73  |  200 |  23-Feb-19 |  27-Feb-19  | 3.598854167 |
|  74  |  200 |  6-Feb-19  |   5-Mar-19  | 26.54347222 |
|  75  |  200 |  28-Feb-19 |   5-Mar-19  | 4.303773148 |
|  76  |  200 |  12-Feb-19 |   6-Mar-19  | 21.56993056 |
|  77  |  200 |  1-Mar-19  |   6-Mar-19  | 4.597615741 |
|  78  |  200 |  12-Feb-19 |  14-Mar-19  | 29.50417824 |
|  79  |  200 |  7-Mar-19  |  14-Mar-19  | 6.083541667 |
|  80  |  200 |  28-Feb-19 |  28-Mar-19  |  27.5291088 |
|  81  |  200 |  25-Mar-19 |  28-Mar-19  | 2.637824074 |
|  82  |  200 |  29-Jan-19 |  28-Feb-19  | 29.34280093 |
|  83  |  200 |  21-Feb-19 |  28-Feb-19  | 6.233831019 |
|  84  |  200 |  19-Feb-19 |  30-Apr-19  | 69.51832176 |
|  85  |  200 |  7-Feb-19  |   5-Mar-19  | 25.74865741 |
|  86  |  200 |  27-Feb-19 |   5-Mar-19  | 5.380034722 |
|  87  |  200 |  21-Feb-19 |  21-Mar-19  | 27.56310185 |
|  88  |  200 |  19-Mar-19 |  21-Mar-19  | 1.161828704 |
|  89  |  200 |  26-Feb-19 |  28-Mar-19  | 29.41315972 |
|  90  |  200 |  22-Mar-19 |  28-Mar-19  | 5.673703704 |
|  91  |  200 |  26-Feb-19 |  28-Mar-19  |  29.5131713 |
|  92  |  200 |  20-Mar-19 |  28-Mar-19  | 7.073414352 |
|  93  |  200 |  28-Feb-19 |  15-Apr-19  | 45.63513889 |
|  94  |  200 |  5-Apr-19  |  15-Apr-19  | 9.479456019 |
|  95  |  200 |  1-Mar-19  |  29-Mar-19  | 27.54568287 |
|  96  |  200 |  25-Mar-19 |  29-Mar-19  | 3.044340278 |
|  97  |  200 |  4-Mar-19  |  27-Mar-19  | 22.52392361 |
|  98  |  200 |  21-Mar-19 |  27-Mar-19  | 5.074421296 |
|  99  |  200 |  14-Feb-19 |  19-Mar-19  | 32.54349537 |
|  100 |  200 |  13-Mar-19 |  19-Mar-19  | 5.265266204 |
```

My current SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    Step,
    ROUND(MEDIAN(Part_Finish - Step_Start), 2) AS "The_Median",
    ROUND(AVG(Part_Finish - Step_Start), 2) AS "The_Average",
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.20) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (Part_Finish - Step_Start) ASC) AS "Best_Time",
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.80) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (Part_Finish - Step_Start) ASC) AS "Worst_Time"

FROM
    myTbl

GROUP BY
    Step
```

However, I am not sure if my results are correct, because I don't think I am using `PERCENTILE_CONT()` correctly. How can I use `PERCENTILE_CONT()` (or another method) to find the average or median (whichever is easier) "time to complete" based on the best 20% of the data, and the worst 20% of the data?

I would expect some results to look like this:

```
| Step | The_Average | The_Median | Best_Time | Worst_Time |
|:----:|:-----------:|:----------:|:---------:|:----------:|
|  200 |  < value >  |  < value > | < value > |  < value > |
```

where the `< value >` fields are the properly calculated average, median, and best and worst of the dataset. Best and worst being calculated by finding the average or median of the top 20% of the data (i.e., the smallest times) or the worst 20% of the data (i.e., the largest times)

Comment: The requirement is a tad unclear, at least to me. Could you [edit] your question and add the expected result?

Comment: Added @Mureinik

Comment: Can you [edit] your post so the data is given as DDL/DML statements (or as a [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c13cfede80a874ee0ffecba429b0c0de)) so that we can easily make use of it? (Rather than having to manually edit it into something useable).

Comment: The problem doesn't make a lot of sense - mathematically (nothing to do with programming). Your dataset either is parametric, or it isn't. In the first case you would care about average, in the latter about median. It is exceptionally rare that you would find practical uses for both, for the same data set. Worse: if you isolate the top 20% or bottom 20% (a non-parametric statistic), then you take the **average** of those values, you are mixing parametric and non-parametric statistics within the same computation; reason to fail an intro course in Statistics.

Comment: Of course, it does make sense to ask for the median, and the 20th and 80th percentile. Then within the top and the bottom 20% you may ask for the *median* (but not for the *average* - that doesn't make sense). Point is, though, that **by definition** the median of the top 20% or bottom 20% is **exactly** the 10th, resp. 90th percentile of the data set; they can be computed directly, there is no need for a convoluted computation.

Comment: That is the point. The requirement is to determine both values to see what sense we can make of the dataset. I think your comments miss the purpose of my question, or I didn't phrase it in a way that is digestible to you. The question is closed and this comment adds no value.@mathguy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PERCENTILE_CONT` is a window function, so if you just want a result set consisting of a single record with scalar values, you may try selecting distinct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Part_Finish - Step_Start) AS "The_median",
    ROUND(AVG(Part_Finish - Step_Start) OVER (ORDER BY Part_Finish - Step_Start), 2) AS "The_Average",
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.20) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Part_Finish - Step_Start) AS "Best_Time",
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.80) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Part_Finish - Step_Start) AS "Worst_Time"
FROM myTbl;
```

The reason for the above approach is that selecting `PERCENTILE_CONT`, a window function, over your entire table would just return the entire table as the result set.  But, as you are using it, the values would always be the same for each record.  Therefore, we can just take the distinct value to get a single result.

If you instead expect a different report for each `Step` value, then you should be using `PARTITION BY` in the calls to `PERCENTILE_CONT`, e.g.

```
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (PARTITION BY Step
    ORDER BY Part_Finish - Step_Start) AS "The_median"
```

Comment: this is great, thank you so much. Is there a way to use this answer to further expand the analytics of the window function, say finding the average of the top and bottom 20%?

Comment: @JerryM. That's really a different question than what you asked.

Comment: Okay, I will post another question then, thank you for your help.

Comment: This is completely wrong. `PERCENTILE_CONT` is both an aggregate and an analytic function. The way you wrote it in the first part of the Answer it is an aggregate function. Without a `GROUP BY` clause, each `PERCENTILE_CONT` function will return exactly one value over the entire table; there is no need for `DISTINCT`.

Comment: More importantly, see my comments under the OP’s question.